# How to configure the custom camera for taking clear image as like default camera in android

Tags: android, image, camera, surfaceview

How to configure the custom camera for taking a clear image as like default camera in android.Please help me. My custom camera is taking blur image.The Even camera view is looking blur. I applied FOCUS_MODE_AUTO, FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE and FOCUS_MODE_MACRO but it still looking blur. Thanks.

Comment: use this lib : https://github.com/florent37/CameraFragment

Comment: I got the solution by calling camera.takepicture in Camera.AutoFocusCallback.

Comment: I had added focus mode in camera parameter but I hadn't called AutofocusCallback. so that's why my camera preview was looking blurred.